# AngularFire: How To Access Firestore Only When Authenticated

Tags: firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I would like to limit Firestore access to authenticated users using AngularFire but am getting the following error:

```
core.js:6456 ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new e (prebuilt-109c6673-0f51e182.js:188)
    at prebuilt-109c6673-0f51e182.js:10416
    at prebuilt-109c6673-0f51e182.js:10414
    at e.onMessage (prebuilt-109c6673-0f51e182.js:10403)
    at prebuilt-109c6673-0f51e182.js:10356
    at prebuilt-109c6673-0f51e182.js:10387
    at prebuilt-109c6673-0f51e182.js:15194
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:134)
    at zone.js:1276
```

I created a very basic test application to test this.

#### app.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="auth.user | async as user; else showLogin">
  <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let profile of profiles | async">{{profile.DisplayName}}</li>
  </ul>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #showLogin>
    <p>You must sign in to continue.</p>
    <button (click)="signIn()"> SIGN IN </button>
</ng-template>
```

#### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'test-auth';
  profiles: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor (
    public auth: AngularFireAuth,
    private firestore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.profiles = firestore.collection('UserProfiles').valueChanges();
  }

  signIn(): void {
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }

  signOut(): void {
    this.auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

#### My Firestore Rules

If the read rule is changed to only "allow read;" the application above works as expected.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents/{document=**} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null;
    allow write: if request.auth != null;
  }
}
```

#### My Versions

```
Angular CLI: 12.0.3
Node: 14.17.0
Package Manager: npm 7.13.0
OS: linux x64

Angular: 12.0.3
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1200.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.0.3
@angular-devkit/core            12.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.0.3
@angular/fire                   6.1.5
@schematics/angular             12.0.3
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.2.4

$ firebase --version
9.12.1
```

### However - raw Firebase works as expected.

With the following code, I have isolated this issue to (1) a bug (?) in AngularFire or (2) my inability to properly implement AngularFire in the code provided in my prior comment.

#### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

export interface ProfileModel {
  Id: string,
  DisplayName: string
}
export interface CurrentUser {
  uid: string;
  name?: string;
  email?: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  title = 'test-auth';
  currentUser: CurrentUser | null = null;
  profilesArray: ProfileModel[] = [];
  fb: firebase.app.App;
  fs: firebase.firestore.Firestore;
  profilesCollection: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference<firebase.firestore.DocumentData>;
  unsubscribe?: firebase.Unsubscribe;

  constructor () {
    this.fb = firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: "OMITTED",
      authDomain: "angularfiretestapp.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://angularfiretestapp.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "angularfiretestapp",
      storageBucket: "angularfiretestapp.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "OMITTED",
      appId: "OMITTED",
      measurementId: "OMITTED"  
    });
    this.fs = firebase.firestore();
    this.profilesCollection = this.fs.collection('UserProfiles');
  }

  ngOnDestroy():void {
    if (this.unsubscribe) {
      this.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  ngOnInit():void {
    this.unsubscribe = this.fb.auth().onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
      if (authUser) {
        this.currentUser = {
          uid: authUser.uid,
          name: authUser.displayName ? authUser.displayName : '',
          email: authUser.email ? authUser.email : ''
        };
        this.profilesArray = [];
        this.profilesCollection.get().then(qSnap => {
          qSnap.forEach(doc => {
            this.profilesArray.push({
              Id: doc.id,
              DisplayName: doc.get('DisplayName')
            });
          });
        });
      } else {
        this.currentUser = null;
      }  
    });
  }

  signIn(): void {
    this.fb.auth().signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }

  signOut(): void {
    this.fb.auth().signOut();
  }
}
```

#### app.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="currentUser; else showLogin">
    <p>Here are some profiles:</p>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let profile of profilesArray">{{profile.DisplayName}}</li>
    </ul>
    <button (click)="signOut()"> SIGN OUT </button>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #showLogin>
    <p>You must sign in to continue.</p>
    <button (click)="signIn()"> SIGN IN </button>
</ng-template>
```

#### Posted Elsewhere

Issue [2838](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2838) filed on GitHub.

Also posted on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/nurlfw/angularfire_how_to_access_firestore_only_when/).

My code is available in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/JeffThurston/angular-fire-auth-issue-2838).

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor it should look more like this

```html
auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user && user.emailVerified) {
        this.profiles = firestore.collection('UserProfiles').valueChanges();
    } else {
        signIn();
    }
});
```

If it still throws exceptions you could try downgrading firebase to 8.3.0.